# clang static analyzer stops analyzing code after std::make_shared

Tags: c++, clang-static-analyzer

In this code, after std::make_shared, static analyzer can't find bugs anymore (for example division by zero). Did anyone have similar problem or know why is this happening? Also, It works fine for make_unique.

```
#include <memory>
int main()
{

 auto b = std::make_shared<int>(new int(10));
 1/0;
}
```

Comment: As a guess, it appears to me that the analyzer ran into the bad `make_shared` line of code, and was unable to semantically continue parsing.

Comment: So there's nothing i can do about that ?

Comment: You can fix the bad line of code, and then run the static analyzer again.  Also, you can compile with all warnings enabled, which can go further even with errors albeit with less aggressive analysis than what the static analyzer does, but can continue further.  (Although to be honest, often the first error makes everything afterwards a bit suspect.)

Comment: Clang static analyzer is a good thing but you shouldn't expect too much from it. Try to use more specialized tools of static code analysis. For example, PVS-Studio provides two warnings on division line: V609 [CWE-369] Divide by zero. and V607 Ownerless expression '1 / 0'.